# Is it possible to make "uwsgi" die when its only worker dies?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a uwsgi based application (one worker) deployed in a Kubernetes cluster and I would like to have worker crashes/failures handled by Kubernetes instead of uwsgi.

I checked the following docs, but that wasn't helpful

- https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html
- https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html

Appreciate your hints.